# Need to store a variable across browsers and email?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, local-storage, storage

It's a pretty large sum of data being stored so I don't want to do it via a database. Cookies don't seem to be applicable since they are not cross browser. I found this https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage which seems to operate cross domain, but I'm not certain how I would go about grabbing this data within an email or even email client, or if that's possible. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could do this? Preferably a lightweight way. (I need to sync up a timer across emails and browsers. )

Comment: Who says that cookies are not "cross-browser"?

Comment: You have data that's too large for a database and you're considering cookies and localStorage?

Comment: The data itself isn't too large, but the amount of data is too much to use a database. So I'm trying to have each person store there own. and Scott my apologies I meant to say cross domain.

Comment: Whatever, the question title still reads "across browsers and email". If you want to share data between different browsers from the same user (e.g. work and home) with client-side technologies or use JavaScript in email messages you're totally out of luck.